# How to set different delays for the same function click event

Tags: javascript, css, function, toggle, delay

I need some help regarding this javascript code that I have implemented on my website. Basically when clicking the hamburger on the fixed header, the fullscreen mobile menu is shown but before it completely appears I have set an animation which lasts for .25 seconds.
By clicking on the hamburger I am triggering the class `header-proper-state` to set the header position to `relative` in order to be able to see and use the hamburger on `fixed` position when the menu is shown. Everything works except the thing that for those .25 seconds the header is missing and creates an unpleasant visual effect before the fullscreen menu is completely shown. As workaround I have set a 300ms delay for the `toggle` and I have no visual issues before the menu is completely shown but when I click again on the hamburger close button, I have to wait 300ms more to see the header on fixed position. So I have tried to change `toogle` to `add` and also to set a different delay (like 40) for a new function when clicking on the close button `is-active` and used `remove` to remove the class that positions the header on `relative` while the meby us shown, in order to have the correcte delays but I am getting errors from console and no class is removed, basically it says that `close` is null. What am I missing?

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  let hamb = document.querySelector('.hamburger')
  let bdy = document.querySelector('body')
  let close = document.querySelector('.is-active')

  hamb.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle('is-active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.mobile-menu').classList.toggle('mob-menu-show')
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.mob-menu-base').classList.toggle('mob-menu-base-anim')
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-content').classList.toggle('mobile-menu-animations')
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.header-wrapper').classList.add('header-proper-state')
    }, 300);
    bdy.classList.toggle('prevent-scroll');
  });

  close.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.header-wrapper').classList.remove('header-proper-state')
    }, 40);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `close` is set at the start of the code. It will at that time be `null` as there are no elements with the is-active `class`.

It appears that it is never changed so when you come to do the `addEventListener` on it you get the error.

The variable `close` needs updating each time before it is used to make sure it refers to the current element that has `class="is-active"`.